# Javascript drag and drop image

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

What I have so far is that on the right hand side there is a set of logos and when you drag it to the left into a box, another image pops out which is a screenshot to the site.

What i need help on is that when i drag it to the left and the screenshot appears i woould like that below the screenshot appears.

The link to the site,
The name of the site,
And a bio of what the site is.

Index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="drag.css" />
<title>Drag and Drop</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="dragTo" class="dragToArea"><img id="largeImage" /><div id="textual" class="textual"></div></div>
    <div id="dragFrom" class="dragFromArea"></div>
</body>


<script src="drag.js"></script>
</html>
```

Javascript file

```
var Resource = function(thumb,textual){ // Creates a prototype of Resource
    var self = this; // Declares variable self as this( refers to the "Owner" of the function being executed )
    self.thumbImage= document.createElement('img'); // Creates an image tag within dragFrom div
    self.thumbImage.setAttribute('src',thumb); // Sets source of image tag to the called upon variable thumb
    self.thumbImage.setAttribute('class','draggable'); // Creates a class on the image called draggable
    document.getElementById('dragFrom').appendChild(self.thumbImage); // Displays the image with set attributes listed above
    self.thumbImage.setAttribute('id', thumb.slice(12,13))


        self.textual = textual;

    whichicon=thumb.slice(12,13);

    self.dragStartHandler = function(e){
        e.target.style.opacity='0.4'; // Sets the opacity of the draggable image when dragging starts

    };

    self.dragEndHandler = function(e){
        if(isInRightSpot){ // Checks to see if isInRightSpot = true
            e.target.style.opacity='1'; // Resets opacity if isInRightSpot = true
            document.getElementById('largeImage').setAttribute('src', 'images/big' +e.target.id + '.png'); // Sets image tag in dragTo to images/big.png if isInRightSpot = true
                        document.getElementById('textual').innerHTML =  e.target.textual;
        }else{
            e.target.style.opacity='1'; // Resets opacity if isInRightSpot = false

        }
    };

    self.thumbImage.addEventListener('dragstart',self.dragStartHandler); // Adds an event listener for the start of dragging of the image in dragFrom
    self.thumbImage.addEventListener('dragend',self.dragEndHandler); // Adds an event listener for the end of dragging(releasing the image) of the image in dragFrom
}

var isInRightSpot = false; // Declares variable isInRightSpot and sets defualt value of false

var dragToSpot = document.getElementById('dragTo'); // Sets dragToSpot to target the dragTo div

dragToSpot.addEventListener('dragover',draggedOver); // Adds event listener for dragging over
function draggedOver(){
    dragToSpot.style.border = "2px dotted"; // Sets border style of dragTo div
    dragToSpot.style.opacity = "0.7"; // Sets opacity of background of dragTo div
    isInRightSpot = true; // Sets the value of isInRightSpot so that draged image can be dropped
};

dragToSpot.addEventListener('dragleave',draggedOut);// Adds event listener for dragging out
function draggedOut(){
    dragToSpot.style.border = "2px solid #777777"; // Resets border style of dragTo div
    dragToSpot.style.opacity = "1"; // Resets opacity of background of dragTo div
    if (mousedown){                 // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        isInRightSpot = false;      // Sets isInRightSPot to false only when the mouse button is in the down position
    }                               // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
};

var smashingMag =  new Resource('images/thumb1.png','test');
var smashingMag1 = new Resource('images/thumb2.png','22222222222');
var smashingMag2 = new Resource('images/thumb3.png','3333333333333');
var smashingMag3 = new Resource('images/thumb4.png','444444444'); // Creates a variable of smashingMag and sets Resource's thumb to images/thumb.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add code in the `if(isInRightSpot){` part something that checks which image is being dragged and then adds the appropriate information?